# How to make a selection with a particular probability defined in table for each rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on some kind of game database there is a table I created. Table consist of `ID, ItemCodeName, ItemCount, ItemPlus, Ratio` columns. My aim is when a particular procedure executed one of the row selected with a particular probability that is defined in this table.

I defined a `rand()` function returning a random number between 1 and 10000 then, To be able to choose one row, I used "with cte" statement that is taking sum of ratio*10000 value row by row. After that, I got stuck, I cannot select one row. I know that logic behind this situation, but i cannot succeed this in SQL.

So, what is your solutions? Also, performance is very important for this situation. This code section will be use continuously.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PICK_AdvancedElixir]
(
        [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [ItemCodeName] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
        [ItemCount] [INT] NULL,
        [ItemPlus] [INT] NULL,
        [Ratio] [REAL] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT PICK_AdvancedElixir ON

INSERT INTO PICK_AdvancedElixir (ID, ItemCodeName, ItemCount, ItemPlus, Ratio) 
VALUES (1, 'ITEM_ETC_ARCHEMY_UPPER_REINFORCE_RECIPE_WE_RARE_B_10', 1, 0, 0.1),
       (2, 'ITEM_ETC_ARCHEMY_UPPER_REINFORCE_RECIPE_SH_RARE_B_10', 1, 0, 0.2),
       (3, 'ITEM_ETC_ARCHEMY_UPPER_REINFORCE_RECIPE_AR_RARE_B_10', 1, 0, 0.3),
       (4, 'ITEM_ETC_ARCHEMY_UPPER_REINFORCE_RECIPE_AC_RARE_B_10', 1, 0, 0.4)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT PICK_AdvancedElixir OFF
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Selection]
    @SelectedRow INT
AS
    DECLARE @ReturnedValue INT = (CONVERT(INT, CEILING(RAND() * 9999)));   -- Returns a number between 1-10000

    WITH CTE(ID, ItemCodeName, SumRatio, Ratio) AS
    (
        SELECT
            A.ID,
            A.ItemCodeName,
            CONVERT(INT, 10000 * (SELECT SUM(Ratio) 
                                  FROM PICK_AdvancedElixir B 
                                  WHERE B.ID <= A.ID)) AS SumRatio,
            A.Ratio
        FROM 
            PICK_AdvancedElixir A
    )
    SELECT 
        ItemCodeName, SumRatio 
    FROM 
        CTE
```

Comment: Can we remove the MySQL tag?

Comment: Done...........

Comment: Are you trying to pick one at random using a weighted value so that some are more likely than others?

Comment: If you want performance you should probably restructure this. Maybe instead of ratio you could have a `num` field and set that to  `0`, `10`, `30`, `60` - then generate a random number between `0 - 99` and seek the first row where  `num < random_number` as ordered by `num` descending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build ratio intervals, then match the random value against one:

```
DECLARE @Random FLOAT = RAND()

;WITH OddIntervals AS
(
    SELECT
        O.*,
        OddStart = CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), SUM(O.[Ratio]) OVER (ORDER BY O.[ID]) - O.[Ratio]),
        OddsEnd = CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), SUM(O.[Ratio]) OVER (ORDER BY O.[ID]))
    FROM
        PICK_AdvancedElixir AS O
)
SELECT
    O.*
FROM
    OddIntervals AS O
WHERE
    @Random > O.OddStart AND
    @Random <= O.OddsEnd
```

The intervals are:

```
ID  Ratio       OddStart    OddsEnd
1   0.1         0.00        0.10
2   0.2         0.10        0.30
3   0.3         0.30        0.60
4   0.4         0.60        1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * from PICK_AdvancedElixir P1 
                        CROSS APPLY 
                            (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(ratio), 0) cum 
                                      FROM PICK_AdvancedElixir P2 WHERE P2.id < p1.id
                             ) SEGL
                                                    CROSS APPLY 
                            (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(ratio),0) cum FROM 
                                       PICK_AdvancedElixir P2 WHERE P2.id <= p1.id
                            ) SEGH

                            CROSS APPLY 
                            (SELECT Rand() as r) RAN
                 WHERE segl.cum <= RAN.r  AND Ran.r < segh.cum
```

this sums all te probabilities including and exclusing the current probability, to build ranges 
[0, .1), 
[.1, .3), 
[.3, .6), 
[.6, 1.0)

then cross apply to a random value and pick the range it is in - the higher probs have larger ranges

note that RAND() is documentd as never producing 1.0